# Can mongo integrate JSON from a document prop into a query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have some documents in mongo that are essentially saved filters consisting of a `name` string and `query` JSON, along with some other properties, so for example:

```
{
  name: "myFilter",
  query: { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2" },
  groupId: 'xxxyyy'
}
```

What I want to be able to do is have an aggregation that applies each filter's query so we can find which ones have matches without fetching and executing each individually.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
$lookup {
  from: "users",
  localField: "groupId",
  foreignField: "groupId",
  as: "users",
  let: {
    q: "$query",
  },
  pipeline: [
    { $match: { $expr: "$$q" } },
}
```

the problem is that this matches all users every time, I think because `$$q` is interpreted as a json blob which `$expr` treats as truthy without parsing it as if it was part of the query. I get the same result if I replace `"$$q"` with `{foo: "bar"}`, `"foo"` or `true`.

What I need is the equivalent of an `exec()` function that will make mongo actually treat this JSON as if it had been typed into the pipeline definition.

Recognizing that there may be security concerns around this, does anyone know if it's possible?

---

**EDIT** by request, adding example docs and expected output.

First, I neglected to include the `groupId` prop in the Filter example above, which I've now corrected. The groupId is just a way to separate users into large cohorts, which we then subdivide with filters.

Here's a complete example:

Filters:

```json
[
  {
    name: "malesOver20",
    query: { gender: "M", age: { $gte: 21 } },
    groupId: "xxxyyy"
  },
  {
    name: "allUnder21",
    query: { age: { $lt: 21 } },
    groupId: "xxxyyy"
  }
]
```

Users:

```
[
  {
    name: "Joe Schmoe",
    gender: "M",
    age: 30,
    groupId: 'xxxyyy'
  },
  {
    name: "Kerry Berry",
    gender: "F",
    age: 19,
    groupId: 'xxxyyy'
  },
  {
    name: "Sanjay Manjay",
    gender: "M",
    age: 21,
    groupId: 'xxxyyy'
  }
  {
    name: "Jimmy Pimmy",
    gender: "M",
    age: 8,
    groupId: 'aaabbb'
  }
]
```

By applying a filter like this to the filters collection...

```
[
  { 
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "groupId",
      foreignField: "groupId",
      as: "users",
      let: {
        q: "$query",
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: "$$q" } },
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to get a result like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "malesOver20",
    query: { gender: "M", age: { $gte: 21 } },
    groupId: "xxxyyy",
    users:
      [
        { name: "Joe Schmoe", gender: "M", age: 30, groupId: "xxxyyy" },
        { name: "Sanjay Manjay", gender: "M", age: 21, groupId: "xxxyyy" },
      ],
  },
  {
    name: "allUnder21",
    query: { age: { $lt: 21 } },
    groupId: "xxxyyy",
    users: [{ name: "Kerry Berry", gender: "F", age: 19, groupId: "xxxyyy" }],
  },
]
```

Normally there would be further filters applied in that pipeline, but this is the part where we're stuck. I hope that helps clarify things!

Comment: Can you add some sample documents from the two collections and the expected output?

Comment: I am afraid this isn't possible. Any expression within $expr which doesn't contains filter operators and is not null evaluates to true. So `$$q` in your query will always evaluate to true. You will have to run separate queries for this.

Comment: Are you directly querying mongodb, or you wqnt some application code to do this?

Comment: While the results will be used in code my goal was to do it all in a single mongo query. I can do it by having my code pull each filter and then interpolate its `query` prop into a new query, but that's N+1 queries for N filter documents and I worry about how that will scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a variant of this in 2 queries, by using $facet. Try to convert this piece of code into your choice of language.

```
const filters = db.filters.find();
let facetStage = { $facet: {} };
for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
   facetStage['$facet'][filters[i].name] = [{ $match: filters[i].query }, { $match: { groupId: filters[i].groupId } }]; // Add more stages here
}
const pipeline = [facetStage];
const users = db.users.aggregate(pipeline);
```

In this code, we first find all the filters. Then we loop over them to create a `$facet` stage. In this stage we store the users, matching different filters under a different key, the filter name itself. Then we run this pipeline on the `users` collection.

This should give you output in this format:

```
{
  malesOver20: [
        { name: "Joe Schmoe", gender: "M", age: 30, groupId: "xxxyyy" },
        { name: "Sanjay Manjay", gender: "M", age: 21, groupId: "xxxyyy" },
      ],
  allOver21: [{ name: "Kerry Berry", gender: "F", age: 19, groupId: "xxxyyy" }]
}
```